# Apache AddType text/css .css Ignored

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have made an ,htaccess file in my /font directory with only this line in it (as part of troubleshooting).

```
AddType text/css .css
```

None the less Google Chrome (even 19.0.1053.0 canary) reports that the .css files are returned as: MIME type text/html

http://paulanorman.com/:11 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://paulanorman.com/fonts/iwona-stylesheet.css".

I use Hostgator and have checked in Cpanel that text/css is default on my server for .css

I have also checked using wget on cygwin bash shell and the documents are indeed coming down as text/html

These stylesheets are being ignored. However I have found if I

```
<style ..>
 <?php include "dah dha / style-sheets.css" ?>
</style>
```

one by one in the head of my document all is fine.

However I would like not to have to do that.

Any one solved this? I have read much all over the net about this and it appears as an unexplained fickle problem it seems.

TIA
paul

Comment: I've actually opened each .css in HTMLKit from the web and live saved them back unedited and now everything works fine, so I suspect it is some sort of charset issue. Thing was that for weeks this worked fine, then (automatic Browser(s) updates?) suddenly font .css would not load properly, and absolutely nothing had been changed by me any where.

Comment: I'm experimenting adding to the .htaccess

    AddType text/css; charset=UTF-8 css

Are Browsers especially Chrome, expecting utf-8 by default now?

Comment: You need to use `AddCharset utf-8 .css .js` to add the charset, not AddType. Also do you use none-ascii characters in you css? If not, than there is no need/use to specify utf8.

Comment: I do not use non-ascii, but the files were being treated as if the Browsers could not recognise them. I am now wondering of there was a BOM at the file head added by and editor? This is why --- "I've actually opened each .css in HTMLKit from the web and live saved them back **unedited** and now everything works fine"

Comment: Looks like according to [www.askapache.com](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setting-charset-in-htaccess.html)  this is ok as a one step process with the quote marks

    `AddType 'text/css; charset=UTF-8' css`

Is there a known problem with that?

Comment: Apparently not. I just didn't know you could use addtype for that.

Comment: Thanks, I have been motivated by all this to study the Apache documents and php manual even more throughly on less of a 911 basis :) (sounds obvious I know but so easily overlooked) and I have learnt some neat stuff. I have become convinced that in the busyness of things we need to stop regularly (organised - planed in!) and do a bit of solid study.

Comment: @PaulANormanNZ looks like you answered your own question. If so, please post an answer and accept it, so that this question won't show up in the "unanswered" section. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to www.askapache.com this is ok as a one step process with the quote marks

> AddType 'text/css; charset=UTF-8' css